# Echo nested array's with foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, localization

I have seen many similar issues but none that can help explain my issue.
I have an array called cities, with a nested array for the state that has the cities of that state. It looks like this:

```
$cities = array(
    "ca" => array(
        "los-angeles" => "Los Angeles"
    ),
    "wa" => array(
        "bellingham" => "Bellingham",
        "seattle" => "Seattle",
        "tacoma" => "Tacoma"
    )
);
```

My PHP code to display many HTML `select` fields:

```
<?php
foreach ($cities as $state) {
    echo "<select name='city' id='" . $state . "'>";
    foreach ($state as $city => $name) {
        echo "<option value='" . $city . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }
}
?>
```

The `id` of the `select` is always `Array`. How can I use the key, like "ca" or "wa"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should be using the array key for the select on the states.  Here is my revision of your code. Note that I explicitly have named `state_key` and `state_value` as well as `city_key` and `city_value`. Naming things explicitly like this helps in debugging. I also added a closing `</select>` element so the content renders correctly.

```
foreach ($cities as $state_key => $state_value) {

    echo "<select name='city' id='" . $state_key . "'>";
    foreach ($state_value as $city_key => $city_value) {
        echo "<option value='" . $city_key . "'>" . $city_value . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you! The tips about explicit names I will make sure to use more often! I understand now how the `state-key` and was found. Oh, I did close the `select` tag but I forgot to add it to this question,

Answer (score 0):

Try  uisng `echo "<select name='city' id='" . $state['los-angeles'] . "'>";` instead of `echo "<select name='city' id='" . $state . "'>";`

If you want `ca` as your select element id then use below one,

```
 foreach ($cities as $key=>$state) {
    echo "<select name='city' id='" . $key . "'>";
    foreach ($state as $city => $name) {
      echo "<option value='" . $city . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
   }
 }
```

If you want like `los-angeles` as id of your select element, then use below one

```
   foreach ($cities as $key=>$state) {      
     $SelectId = strtolower(str_replace(" ",'-',$state['los-angeles']));
    echo "<select name='city' id='" . $SelectId . "'>";
    foreach ($state as $city => $name) {
        echo "<option value='" . $city . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first foreach loop is going over an array of arrays. So each member is going to be an array. If you had `id ='" . $state[0]` you would see the first member of said array.

the `var_dump` function is your friend.

You could get all the cities by using `array_keys` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($cities as $key=>$state) {
    echo "<select name='city' id='" . $key . "'>";
    foreach ($state as $city => $name) {
        echo "<option value='" . $city . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }
}
```

change to this

in your case $state is an array containing cities. so it is always showing the value as Array().